# I have created SpreadsheetML and try to open into Excel file. it was unable to open

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel-2007

From [This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8NKY.png)

I have created SpreadsheetML and try to open into Excel file. it was unable to open. because Data node contain nested XML.

Is there any solution for this other than interop excel dll ?

```
<XMl Version="">
    <workbool xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"------>
    ---
    ---
    <Row>
    <Cell ss:styyleID =" -----">
    <data>
     <?XML version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
    <ExecutionDate> 10/10/2017 </ExecutionDate>
    </Data>
    </Cell>
    </Row>
   <Row>
    ---
    ---
   </Worksheet>
   </Workbook>>
```